# Google Analytic - Ecommerce Product Lists

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Enhanced Ecommerce tracking in my website, but for some reason product lists views are not being registered. [Here is a screenshot from analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3mSF.png)

When I print a listing, I set the list name in the "category" attribute of each product, like this:

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {
      'id': 15,
      'name': "Product name",
      'price': "370",
      'category': "Category name"
});
```

Then, once I printed all the products I send the pageview:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I can see that the categories are being received because they appear in the listing, but no views are registered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should add that I'm also sending product views whenever a user clicks in one of the items in those lists using `ga('ec:addProduct', {...}); ga('ec:setAction', 'click', { list: 'Category name' } ); ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Results');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a EE impression list, you need to add in that parameter and value:

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {
  'id': 15,
  'name': "Product name",
  'price': "370",
  'category': "Category name",
  'list': "list name" // add your list name
});
```

More info here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#impression-data